# How to persist Storm metrics? How a Storm topology picks up its metrics history when it restarts?

Tags: history, metrics, apache-storm, persist

I'm totally new to Storm. Here I'm trying to implement Storm metrics. I implemented metrics bolt and consumer which extends `IMetrisConsumer`. I'm looking to  persist my  topology metrics. So when topology restarts it should pickup earlier metrics based on time slots etc. How can I persist metrics and how can a topology picks up all its history?

Answer (score 1):

This is beyond storm. metrics can be stored in many systems. such as Ganglia or OpenTSDB.